# 0% code coverage with PHPUnit

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

I'm running module tests with PHPUnit and want to get coverage reports on the tests. I've successfully been doing this in the past, but somehow i cannot get it working again and I have no idea why it's not working any longer. The only difference is that i now run PHP 5.4 instead of 5.3.

The tests are run in an Ant build file with the exec command:

```
<exec dir="${basedir}" executable="phpunit.bat" failonerror="${test.failonerror}">
    <arg value="--log-junit" />
    <arg value="${test.phpunit.log}" />
    <arg value="--coverage-clover" />
    <arg value="${test.phpunit.coverage.log}" />
    <arg value="--bootstrap" />
    <arg value="${test.phpunit.bootstrap}" />
    <arg value="${test.phpunit.testdir}" />
</exec>
```

Here is a snippet of the Ant log when i run my tests:

```
module-test-php:
     [exec] PHPUnit 3.6.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.
     [exec] .............
     [exec] Time: 5 seconds, Memory: 8.75Mb
     [exec] OK (13 tests, 113 assertions)
     [exec] Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... done
```

From the log, it appears that coverage reporting should work, but when I open the report, all I get is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coverage generated="1344329670">
  <project timestamp="1344329670">
    <metrics files="0" loc="0" ncloc="0" classes="0" methods="0" coveredmethods="0" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="0" coveredstatements="0" elements="0" coveredelements="0"/>
  </project>
</coverage>
```

Is there some setting I'm missing here or why do I get zero coverage?

**Update**

I did some more testing and found bug relating to phar archives. The issue has been reported.

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/issues/107

Answer (score 0):

Codecoverage is about the source-code form. The source-code form is the variant of the software you make changes to.

A phar file is an archive. Similar to PHP code encoded by Zend Encoder or Ioncube Encoder or even APC, code coverage can not work for these and more importantly: Code coverage as a metric does not make any sense to work for these files.

So you might just wonder, but wonder twice and think about why it is this way. Try to find an explanation in your own words why reporting code-coverage for phar files is of no use.